# Collecting color picker data from HTML form to use in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, forms

```
<form action="example.php" method="get">
   
        <label>Choose a color: </label>
        <input type="color" name="favcolor"><br>


        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Im having a hard time trying to figure this out, hoping someone could assist.

If a user chooses a color from the color picker, how do i save that specific color so that i can transfer it into my PHP file in order to use that color on text for example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It’s not clear exactly what your requirement is or what “*save*” means to you specifically, but you can “*transfer*” this choice by making a call to your PHP back-end with the choice information itself and process and store it there to ultimately retrieve it back in subsequent accesses as your requirements dictate.

Comment: How does your submit work? Does it save to a DB or just to a URL parameter? Basically, the idea would be to as follows: Once the user submits, it gets sent to either your url parameter in the new page. That new page reads this parameter and activates a class with that color set in css. The concept is something like that.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve your question? What happens if you submit the form? Isn't the data added to the request? Also, how is this question related to CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you will find this as a good solution.  Works with me,  using XAMPP as server

I use 3 languages in HTML page using this code:  **English, Arabic, and *Urdu*.**

I use core PHP coding with a slight touch of JavaScript.

Codes for 2 files
color.html and action.php

```
    <html>
    <head>

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;  charset=UTF-8">  

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ur" /> 
 <title> Color  Picker in Php , for Webpage having Urdu, English and Arabic Content   </title> 
    </head>

  <body> 
  <form method="POST" action="action.php">
  <label for="favcolor">Select your favorite color:</label>
  <input type="color" id="favcolor" name="favcolor"  value="#1919f5"> 
 <br><br>
 <input type="submit">
 </form>

 Save this as  color.html 
 <br> 
 and   php file  as action.php 
 <br>
 When you Press submit, data is passed using  POST method and processed.  
 </body>
  </html>
```

PHP based example

```
    <html>
    <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;  charset=UTF-8">  

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ur" /> 
 <title> Color  Picker in Php , for Webpage having Urdu, English and Arabic Content   </title> 

    </head>
    <body>
```

Note:  This PHP function **extracts the FORM data submitted via POST method**. It assigns a variable $newColor the value passed by id=favcolor.

```
    <?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")   {  
        //  to be used with empty input or on First visit of page 
            if (!empty($_POST["favcolor"])) 
            {$newColor  = test_input($_POST["favcolor"]);} 
            else $newColor  = "#ff19f5";    
          } 
/*
Note:  This PHP function **removes unneccasry charaters from FORM data**. Hackers attempt to embed their codes in form data and manipulate to hack you website and database.   **It is to prevent hackers' attacks**. May have many more advantages. 
*/

    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
        }
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    
    echo " <p style=\"color:$newColor\">The colour of paragraph is 
 $newColor .</p> "; 
     ?>

 <?php  echo  " Colour Value is " . $newColor ; 
 ?> 

 
<form method="POST" action="action.php">
  <label for="favcolor">Select your favorite color:</label>
  <input type="color" id="favcolor" name="favcolor"  value="<?php echo $newColor ; ?>">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

 
 </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Thank you for guiding me.  I am using this code in a website having  PHP and JavaScript to get form data and pick colors from HTML color selector :  <input type="color">    I have edited the answer to explain each PHP function.

Comment: Please do not use answers to promote your own website

Comment: Noted, please.  Redrafted answer to remove word website as well.  No mention now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <label>Choose a color: </label>
    <input type="color" name="favcolor"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then use this php code that will return in variable the color you pick.

```
<?php
$favcolor = "";
if (isset($_GET['favcolor'])) {
    $favcolor = $_GET['favcolor'];
} else {
    echo "Pick a color!";
}

echo $favcolor;
?>
```

I hope it's work for you.